# django: South does not generate the same index names depending on platform

Tags: mysql, linux, django, windows, django-south

I'm working on a django application with a MySQL backend. I use south to migrate my schema.
I've just written a migration that drops indexes on some columns, because of a foreign key change AND a name change for said colums.
I did not want to go through the "add the column"->"copy the data"->"remove the old column".

So my migration code chunks look like this (sample given for one table):

```
# Change FK link from 'reference_workobject' to 'assets_asset'
db.delete_foreign_key('reference_snapshot', 'workObject_id')
db.delete_index('reference_snapshot', ['workObject_id'])
db.rename_column('reference_snapshot', 'workObject_id', 'asset_id')
db.alter_column('reference_snapshot', 'asset_id',
                self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey')(null=True, to=orm['assets.Asset'])
```

But I get an error that looks like:

```
DatabaseError: (1091, "Can't DROP 'reference_snapshot_6232368c; check that column/key exists")
```

Indeed, I fed my development DB (Windows 7 workstation) with a dump from the production server (CentOS 6.5). And I saw that the call to the index name generation (`db.create_index_name`) does not return the same value on the distinct platforms.

```
>>> # On WINDOWS
>>> db.create_index_name('reference_snapshot',['workObject_id'])
'reference_snapshot_6232368c'

>>> # On Linux
>>> db.create_index_name('reference_snapshot',['workObject_id'])
'reference_snapshot_9dcdc974'
```

After investigation, I saw that south should generate my index name as follows:

```
index_name = '%s_%x' % (table_name, abs(hash((column_name,))) % 2**32)
```

#### EDIT

<del>Executing such code snippet yields the same value on both platforms. However the call to `create_index_name`does not. Paradox. Maybe south is not using the code I thought it would.</del>

The call to that snippet of code does actually yields differents results.

```
>>> # On windows
>>> hash((column_name,))
1965709063

>>> # On Linux
>>> hash((column_name,))
-791966850447943929
```

If the 32 bits truncation/padding (`% 2**32`) part was made without the call to `abs()`, though, the results would be the same.

I conclude from this that the hashing is 32 bits based on windows (even if I use a 64bits python), and 64 bits based on linux.

#### end edit

So I'm stuck as I can't use the production dumps on windows so as to test my migrations. 
Any ideas? Maybe monkey-patching something on my dev workstation could do the trick.

Thanks

Comment: And the funny part is: sometimes I have identical results: when the hashing result on linux is positive (>0), the 32 bits truncation then gives the same value as under windows.

Answer (score 0):

Too bad. We can't help but suffer the differences in hash implementation. 
However I've just read that the index name calculation will now (as of django 1.5) use md5 because of Python3's randomization in hash(). http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/1222